# VWD 2010 - App.config for debug, staging and production in Class library

Tags: c#, visual-web-developer-2010

How come am I getting 3 files when creating a config file in web project in VWD, and in class library I get only one config file (`App.config`)?

I have a solution with 1 web project and 2 class libraries that requires 3 different config files for debug, staging and production.
how do I handle it in the class libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should really not care about this because the class library at runtime will not use its own `app.config` or the result of its compilation into `classlibrary.edll.config`.

At runtime all needed configuration for the class library will need to be present in the `web.config` because the .NET runtime will read from there ignoring the original app.config.

Comment: Thanks, so why do I have this option of "add new item"?

Comment: because you still add the keys there and you can distribute the file as an example of required configuration. Or do you prefer to note down those things by hand?